# Applying constants in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say we have a list `mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, and we want to generate another list like this: `['a:1', 'a:2', 'b:1', 'b:2', 'c:1', 'c:2']`, which basically appends `':1'` and `':2'` to each element of `mylist`.

I wonder how to do this efficiently using list comprehension, if possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
['%s:%d' % (e, i) for e in mylist for i in (1, 2)]
```

Comment: -1 because nested loops in comprehensions are difficult to understand, and may not be familiar to OP.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most efficient way to do this is with `itertools.product`:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
from itertools import product

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
mysuffixes = [':1', ':2']
result = [x+y for x, y in product(mylist, mysuffixes)]
```

The exact construction might vary depending on how your constants are defined.

Comment: thanks! But I wonder how efficient is this one comparing to the pure list comprehension approach by mata above?

Comment: One simple test I set up using the `timeit` module shows them about the same for a 10000-length mylist and a 2-length suffix list, testing with 1000 repetitions each time.  I've seen either version beat the other when run one after the other - in the most extreme version, the product version took 3.11 seconds for 1000 repetitions while the list comprehension version took 4.57.  On the other hand, I also saw the list comprehension version take 3.26s while the product version took 4.08s.  This is not exactly rigorous analysis but it looks like any difference in speed will be small.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a=['a','b','c']
>>> b=[1,2]
>>> import itertools
>>> ['%s:%s' % (x,y) for x,y in itertools.product(a,b)]
['a:1', 'a:2', 'b:1', 'b:2', 'c:1', 'c:2']
```

Comment: And now I think we have three answers showing all three of the obvious ways to construct the final strings from the tuples `itertools.product` yields (string concatenation, string interpolation, and `join`).

Answer (score 3):

```
In [4]: mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [5]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[e+":1", e+":2"] for e in mylist]))
Out[5]: ['a:1', 'a:2', 'b:1', 'b:2', 'c:1', 'c:2']
```

Comment: Nice approach - it didn't occur to me (or apparently anyone else) to effectively precompute the product.

Answer (score 3):

This concept is the same as `itertools.product`

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(mylist, ('1', '2')))
[('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '1'), ('c', '2')]
```

As product returns tuples you have to join that tuples with `:` I think this solution is the clearest:

```
>>> map(':'.join, product(mylist, ('1', '2')))
['a:1', 'a:2', 'b:1', 'b:2', 'c:1', 'c:2']
```